# Shortest path in 2d arrays

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, shortest-path

```
*...*..D
.G..*.....
**...**.
.S....*.
........
...G**..
........
.G..*...
```

Here is 2d array where

S- Source
D-Destination
G-Point must be visited
." . "Free paths
"*"Block Paths
Can you help me which would be the efficient algorithm to find the length of shortest pathi in java
Only Horizontal and Vertical movements are possiable

Comment: which methods have you found so far, and where is the code to show you've already started working on solving this problem before asking your question on stackoverflow?

Comment: I have code in Dijkstra's algorithm but i want  most efficient way to do so

Comment: Do you need to visit all the G point `before` reaching the D point, or you can visit them in any order? And the question is minimize the total distance to travel, or you just ask how to find the shortest path between two locations?

Comment: yes it is need to visit all the G point before reaching D

Comment: What is the maximum number of G point? 10 ? 20?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the shortest distance from `start` point to all other points in the map, you can use a [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).
Sample code:

```
public void visit(String []map , Point start){
        int []x = {0,0,1,-1};//This represent 4 directions right, left, down , up
        int []y = {1,-1,0,0};
        LinkedList<Point> q = new LinkedList();
        q.add(start);
        int n = map.length;
        int m = map[0].length();
        int[][]dist = new int[n][m];
        for(int []a : dist){
            Arrays.fill(a,-1);
        }
        dist[start.x][start.y] = 0;
        while(!q.isEmpty()){
            Point p = q.removeFirst();
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
                int a = p.x + x[i];
                int b = p.y + y[i];
                if(a >= 0 && b >= 0 && a < n && b < m && dist[a][b] == -1 && map[a].charAt(b) != '*' ){
                    dist[a][b] = 1 + dist[p.x][p.y];
                    q.add(new Point(a,b));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The second path of the problem is actually a [traveling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), so you need to convert from your original graph to a graph which `only contains G,D and S points`, with the `weight` of each edge in this graph is the `shortest path between them in original path`. From that onward, if the number of G is small (less than 17) you can use `dynamic programming and bitmask` to solve the problem.

Comment: @user3952416 hmm , depend on the number of G,D and S. should be fine if G <= 20.

Comment: i am using  BFS search and i am getting a perfect answer from S to D , if i am considering G the output does not give me a optimum value ? How to solve second one

Comment: @PhamTrung, TSP can't be solved with dynamic programming and bitmask :-)

Comment: @aioobe actually it is, you can represent the state by `dp[1<<n][n]`, with the first dimension represents visited cities, and the second one is the current city. I just google and there are alot of result, for example, this [link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/travelling-salesman-problem-set-1/) :)

Comment: @user3952416 you should read more about TSP, which I have added a link , your problem is a modified version of TSP, but you should learn about that first, it requires some advanced technique, which I already mentioned here in my answer:)

Comment: @PhamTrung, sure, but the complexity is exponential!

Comment: @aioobe yes, as I already mentioned in my comment, if G <= 20, this approach will be fine :), so maybe I will add it in my answer also. And as this problem is NP-hard, I think this is the best advice I can give.

Comment: @PhamTrung  I am trying it too hard but can't find the right solution,my approach i of D(i.e 0)<i of S(i.e 3 ) then find the optimum path in lower array i.e(i>3) ,but since it can visited the same path and checkpoints more that's why i am getting a wrong answer?Could you help me.

Comment: @user3952416 hmm, honestly I think it is a little bit too early for you to solve this problem. If you still want to solve it, read more about TSP, it will tell you the reason why any trick/ greedy is not working for this problem, then try to solve the classical TSP using dynamic programming, after all these steps, if you still don't know how to do, come back here and tell us where were you stuck ok :)

Comment: @PhamTrung  could you please explain why are you passing 1-d array ([]map)  since the maze is in 2-d array

Comment: @user3865607 because the map is a string array, so each string represents the whole row, for example {"...S...","....D..."}

Comment: @PhamTrung would you please guide me in bitmask i can't understand a line of code((1<<i)) that is used in recursion function

Answer (score 2):

Here there are many algorithms like dijkstra or BFS but if you need to learn an path finding algorithm then i suggest the [A* algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) as it is quicker than dijkstra or BFS and can be easily implemented on a 2D matrix.
As in case of must visit node you can try all sequences in which you visit the nodes for example say `S->G1->G2->G3->D` find the minimum for this path as `min(S,G1)+min(S,G2)+min(G3,D)`. try all permutations of the `G's` and get the minimum of them all.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple Breadth First search algorithm problem. This is called flood fill technique which is a type of Breadth First search algorithm. Read it from [here.](https://www.princeton.edu/~achaney/tmve/wiki100k/docs/Flood_fill.html) You can also learn the basic Breadth first algorithm from [here.](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=graphsDataStrucs2#breadth) This could also be solved by other techniques like Dijkstra or Floyd warshal. But Breadth first search is easier to understand.